# bootstrap 4 how to change flex order

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have the following code:

```
    <div class="container">
<div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
        <div class="d-flex order-1 flex-column col-11 col-sm-2">
                <img src="im.png" alt="image" class="img-fluid">
        </div>

        <div class="d-flex order-0 flex-column col-sm-8 ">
                        <div><b style="color:red;">Title: </b>work</div>
                        <div><b style="color:red;">Author: </b>mark</div>
                       <div> <b style="color:red;">Country: </b>usa</div>
                       <div><b style="color:red;">city: </b>ny</div

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

what I want is the following:

1. on anything but mobile screen the order of image and the div that
   follow image get swapped so image appear on the right instead of
   right and the div that follow it appears on left
2. on xs screens I  want them both to appear in their default order and each on of them
   full the whole width something like col-12

How to do this? I tried grid and flex but I could not achieve that

Note: I am beginner so sorry for my question which may appear to you naive

Comment: Where is your attempt? Right now you are just asking for someone to do this for you. There are tons and tons of tutorials online that cover what you want to do. Please show some effort first and then come back when you have an actual question about your attempt.

Comment: @antfuentes87 should I include every attempt? I tried by using float-right then by using flexbox then addind col-12. would you kindly point me to some tutorial because from what you said it seems I am using wrong search keyword on google

Comment: Please clarify the question and what's not working. *"image appear on the right instead of right"* doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly use **row** on `<div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">` instead of `d-flex flex-row`. The col-* classes won't work properly without that.

Secondly, use `order-sm-1` class on the div containing the img tag.

Thirdly, remove `col-11` class, its not required.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="d-flex order-sm-1 flex-column col-sm-2">
      <img src="im.png" alt="image" class="img-fluid">
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex flex-column col-sm-8">
      <div><b style="color:red;">Title: </b>work</div>
      <div><b style="color:red;">Author: </b>mark</div>
      <div> <b style="color:red;">Country: </b>usa</div>
      <div><b style="color:red;">city: </b>ny</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```